# Django Rest What Serializer you should use for your api?

Tags: django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework, deserialization, django-serializer

I am new to django and recently started working on django rest framework

I am a little confused about which serializer one should choose while making a serializer for an api

Should it be a ModelSerializer, BaseSerializer or a custom one

I have a scenario where i just want to retrieve certain model fields for a model named User
fields = ['name', 'age']

I want to know what is the best way to achieve this using the correct serializer

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer w/out knowing the specifics of your model.  But it sounds like you want a ModelSerializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from my_app.models import User


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = [
            "name",
            "age",
        ]
```

I'm not sure what you mean by *custom one*.  This is, in effect, a custom serializer, it's just not very customized.  Unless you want non-standard things to happen when working w/ `name` or `age` the above code should work fine.